# converting char array of particular length into a string

Tags: java

i need to convert char array into string , the problem in doing this is......i need to convert the character in char array of particular length say k to string.    ie, char array is "b" .b takes value dynamically.....for instance take as "p,a,p,e,r,s"  now k value also dynamic ,for this word "k=5" ,and then only 4 characters in char array "b" should be converted into string...ie the string should print as "paper"........
the code what i have now is

```
 for(int c=0;c<=k;c++)
 {
      System.out.print(b[c]);
 }
 str=new String(b);
 System.out.println(str);
```

where `b[c]` prints correct value(in char array) as "paper".  While converting to string `str` (in program) it prints as "papers" itself....can anyone give me solution for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a different constructor of [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) that lets you specify the array along with the start point and number of characters to use.

In your case, you would try:

```
str = new String( b, 0, k );
```

Comment: thanks for ur code...it worked when i give as str=new Stirng(b,0,k+1);

Answer (score 1):

```
char newArr[] = new char[k];
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    newArr[i] = b[i];
    System.out.print(b[i]); // print until the kth index
}

return new String(newArr);
```

Comment: thanks for this code.....but i need to print till k value...so i gave "i<=k".....but this is not working....(progarm is not running) .....y this happens so?

Comment: I've edited my answer. If you want to print until the kth index, then it should be i < k, since JAVA arrays are 0-indexed.

Comment: For example, if you have the word "papers", and you feed k = 6, it's not gonna run, since there is not index:6 for that string. Index:5 is the last index.